# Changing Windows locale programmatically without restarting the application

Tags: localization

The WPF application I am working on supports multiple languages. It displays translated text according to the Windows locale. So if Windows is set to German the application will display German text.

I would like to have a single suite of tests to check for localization issues. I don't want to run the same suite of tests for each language. Its a lot of unnecessary repetitive work. To make it work I need an ability to switch to a different language dynamically without restarting the application. I will also need WPF resources to be reloaded dynamically.

Is there a way to do this?